# How can i quickly create a copy of my demo database in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database

i have a demo database, which would be used by many users concurrently. Users can query and modify the data, and query those modified data. but other users should see the changes only made by themselves. when user logs out, i would clear all those changes made by that user.
i know i can just copy the database, and connect to different databases when user log in. but if there 're too many users, i would end up getting a lot of databses in one single server.
i wonder if there's any convinient way to do that.

Comment: do you want replicate database on other server or just want a redirection

Comment: BTW, the database schema and the access C# code is shared across demo system and production system, so i need some clean way to do this job. that means, i want all the changes user make can only persisted in user's context, and auto rollback or undo when user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating Temp tables in SQL

and as soon as the user logout just drop them off.

to create a temp table from your original table

```
Declare @usera varchar(10)
set @usera = 'Ham'

Declare @sql varchar(70)
set @sql = 'use NorthTemp select * into ##temptable_' + @usera + ' from originaltable'

exec (@sql)
```

and allow users to work with the TempTables

am using ## so that the table is global